# Find or find one is returning empty array in mongoose but when i queried in mongo shell find returns value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
Can anyone help me with the error in the below code why find or findOne is returning empty array when a parameter is passed when it has data in database. When i queried vis mongo shell find and find one returns value. Only when parameter is passed it is not returning value but it returns value for find and find one with no parameter passed why??? what mistake???

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        categoryName: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        subcategory: [ {
          
            subcategoryName: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            }]
});

 module.exports = mongoose.model('categories', Schema);

controller code:
------------------
const categories = require('../models/category');
exports.getCategory = (req, res, next) => {

categories.find({"categoryname":{ $regex: req.params.id, $options: 'i' }},(err, products) => {
   console.log("Products:"+JSON.stringify(products));
  if (err) {
         return res.status(400).json({
           error: "No Products found"+err
         });
       }
       res.status(200).json(products)
     });
};

routes code:
-------------
```

const categoryCtrl = require('../controllers/category');
routes.get('/category/getCategory/:id', categoryCtrl.getCategory);

```
GET call URL via postman:
------------------------
http://localhost:3000/category/getCategory/"Fruits"
```

Any mistakes in my code i need help on this

Comment: The query uses `"categoryname"` but the schema uses `"categoryName"` - typo?

Comment: no even after correcting that it is not working. Any other mistakes